# Give root privileges to a PyGtk app

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Or at least one part of the code. Essentially I need for the app to be able to write into `/etc` but that being a root access only directory the app needs to have a root or a fake root access to that directory.
I thought of creating and saving the file to `~/Desktop` so that the user could then use the Terminal to move it to /etc but I abandoned that approach for two reasons:

1. The app is meant to remove the need for using a terminal (this is also why, I don't want to  have the user need to run the app with `$sudo APPNAME`)
2. Having the app drop the file to the Desktop requires it to know the full path, the '~' doesn't seem to work and returns an error.

Comment: Ad 2.: Try expanding the '~' with `os.getenv()` (see [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getenv) ). Even if '~' won't work, 'HOME' should :)

Comment: On 1, I would have the app use http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html and simply have a subprocess running as superuser (Never tried it though but it should be possible to read stdout for the question about password and feed the password to stdin (and any other commands after that).

Comment: `os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")`. You could specify `gksudo /path/to/app` as a command to run your app or only use `gksudo` to replace the file in /etc via `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want cleaner integration with the OS, I would recommend you try using [PolicyKit](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/polkit).

There are various ways to interact with it:

1. Using DBus. You can find a nice example [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1359397).
2. Using the Polkit module through GObject instrospection. [Here's](http://blog.artfwo.net/2011/02/writing-policykit-applications-in.html) an example for this.

In both cases you would need to install a specific [action configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PolicyKit#Actions) for your application on /usr/share/polkit-1/actions (or use an already existing one, like exec).

It probably will take you a little more of effort to implement it this way, but in my opinion is cleaner than a subprocess and makes to a better integration with the OS and the Desktop Enviroment (e.g. the password request dialog is provided by the DE).